# Stick rock particles to the ground

Tags: particles, displacement

i've been trying to create a rocky ground, using a plane and it's particle effect as i saw in some tutorial. However, even if i follow it step by step the rocks used as particles seem to remain floating everywhere around the plane like this:

[image]

The current steps i'm following are:

1. Create the plane and subdivide, then add displace modifier with cloud texture, then apply object->apply->scale
2. Create the rock object
3. Add the particle system to the plane...

Here is my blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/5629ace07f234c6691b8b3961474e02d

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots sure, here you have it https://pasteall.org/blend/5629ace07f234c6691b8b3961474e02d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origins of your particle objects are too far from the meshes. Select your 2 rocks and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry* (or move the meshes in *Edit* mode in order to put the origins wherever you want).